# Selecting Active Policies

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple query that joins two tables as shown below:

```
select
p.policy_id, c.cust_name
from policies p
inner join customers c
on p.policy_id = c.policy_id
```

However, I need to execute the above query only for '`Active`' (i.e. `is_Closed = 'N'`) policies which is stored in another table -

Contract:

```
policy_id | is_Closed
12345 | N
12345 | N
71567 | N
71567 | N
12345 | Y
```

However, looking at the contract table above, we see that `policy_id 12345`, even though it has 2 records with `'N'` (ie `Active`), but it still has 1 record that is `'Y'`, making it is as `Closed`. For a given policy_id, if there is even one record with `'Y'`, it should be considered as `Closed/Inactive` irrespective of whether there are other records for that policy which are `'N'` (ie `Active`) and hence should not be considered in the output.
On the other hand, the policy `71567` has 2 records which are both `'N'` ie both are `Active` and hence should be considered for the query.

I tried something like the below query to ignore `'Closed'` (ie `'Y'`) policies -

```
select
p.policy_id, c.cust_name
from policies p
inner join customers c
on p.policy_id = c.policy_id
where p.policy_id NOT IN (select distinct policy_id from contract where is_Closed = 'Y');
```

But unfortunately this query takes a long time to complete with `125 Mil` records in the contract table. 
Is there any smarter way to implement this logic so that it could execute more efficiently ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try pre-aggregating the `contracts` table:

```
select p.policy_id, c.cust_name
from policies p inner join
     customers c
     on p.policy_id = c.policy_id left join
     (select distinct policy_id
      from contract
      where is_Closed = 'Y'
     ) cy
     on p.policy_id cy.policy_id
where cy.policy_id is null;
```